# How to find the max count of a grouped column in Grails/GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a table with the following columns/values:

```
id    group_id    state    type_id
1       g1         NY         t1
2       g1         NY         t1
3       g1         PA         t1
4       g2         NY         t1
5       g3         CA         t1
6       g4         CA         t2
```

I would like to identify the maximum frequency of a group of group_id, state combinations given a type_id.  To do this in straight SQL I would do something like the following:

```
SELECT MAX (COUNT (*)) AS perGroup
   FROM table_name
  WHERE type_id = t1
GROUP BY group_id, state
```

This seems to work just fine in SQL but when I *attempt to* translate it to a Criteria Builder in Grails/GORM it always gives me a max of 0.

I've tried just getting the count and it *seems* to be working properly. However; this would require me to loop in the groovy code after the db call and I would like to avoid that if I can.

This is what I have that works for the count:

```
Table.createCriteria().list {
    eq("type.id",'t1')
    projections {
        sqlProjection "count(*) as theCount",['theCount'], [INTEGER]
        groupProperty "group"
        groupProperty "state"
    }
}
```

How would I identify the max instead?

For example, given the data in the above scenario I would expect the following output:

- t1 = 2
- t2 = 1

Comment: One way to work around this might be to add a [derived property](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties) to the domain class that gets the grouped count, then use the max() method for your Criteria query on that.

Comment: Also, not to nitpick, but I'm pretty sure the SQL you listed wouldn't work. You'd need sub-querying to get the max number of a count query, I believe. Simply running SQL like that in the Grails h2 DB console returns a 0 for every row. 

This, though, would work: ```SELECT MAX(theCount) from
(select COUNT (*) as theCount FROM STUFF 
group by group_id, state)```.

Given that, some implementation of a DetachedCriteria would probably be best. http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#detachedCriteria

Comment: I get the idea that it MIGHT require a sub query but it doesn't. It works just fine as is when running direct against the database. I'm using TOAD and ORACLE in the event that matters.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Same results on my Oracle DB. I'm playing around with the sqlGroupProjection.

Comment: So, I turned on logSql in my scratch application (which is running against an H2 db, not Oracle). Using this line in the projections block: `sqlGroupProjection "max(count(*)) as max", 'group_Id,state', ['max'], [INTEGER]` produces this query: `Hibernate: select max(count(*)) as max from stuff this_ where this_.type=? group by group_Id,state` and this result: `[0, 0, 0, 0]`. So even though hibernate is translating the query more or less correctly, it's not returning the results we would expect. You might turn on logSql in DataSource.groovy and see what comes back from your Oracle DB.